# How to take time as an input in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

I want to take input time with am/pm using my laravel controller to mysql. But the problem is I have taken the time from blade view but while seeing the output using dd() it's showing following value.

```
Carbon {#213 ▼
  +"date": "2016-05-09 00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
```

Means nothing save as start value.

Here is the Model:

```
class Room extends Model
{
    protected $table='allocate_rooms';             
}
```

Here is the view I've used:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>From</label>
    <input type="time" name="start" class="form-control" required >
</div>
```

Here is the controller I'm using.

```
public function AllocateRoom(Request $request)
{
    $room = new Room();  
    $room->start = Carbon::parse($request->input('start'));
    dd($room->start);
    $room->save(); 
}
```

In my database I have used `time` as datatype for start

Comment: Can you show the Room model and the result of `dd()`

Comment: I have updated the Qus with details!

Comment: What do you get when you do dd($room->start-> getTimestamp()); ?

Comment: Some Number Like I'm getting `1462759200`

Answer (score 2):

In your model you need the date mutator:

```
class Room extends Model
{
     protected $table='allocate_rooms';             
     protected $dates = ['start'];
}
```

More information:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Comment: Same output I'm getting after  adding date mutator!

Answer (score 0):

```
$room->start = Carbon::parse($request->input('start'))->format('h:i a');
```